# Como reaproveitar valores de classes?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Possuo três classes, a terceira depende de valores das outras duas (depende do `E` da classe `Material` e do `A`, `Ix`, `Iu` e `Iz` da classe `Geometria`. Como consigo fazer isso? Sei que preciso corrigir a 3a classe, mas não sei como (ou mesmo se o que está ali está certo).

```
class Material(object):
    def __init__(self, nome, E, ni):
        self.nome = nome
        self.E = E
        self.ni = ni

class Geometria(object):
    def __init__(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome
        self.A = 0.
        self.Ix = 0.
        self.Iy = 0.
        self.Iz = 0.
        self.chi = 0.
    def retangular(self, b, h):
        self.A = b * h
        self.Iz = b * h ** 3 / 12.
        self.Iy = h * b **3 / 12
        self.Ix = ( 1 / 3 - 0.21 * b / h * ( 1 - b ** 4 / ( 12 * h ** 4 ) ) ) * h * b ** 3
        self.chi = 1.2

class SecTrans(Material, Geometria):
    def __init__(self, E, A, Iz, Iy, Ix):
        self.EA = E*A
        self.EIz = E*Iz
        self.EIy = E*Iy
        self.EIx = E*Ix
```

Comment: Tem como você descrever o que é cada classe? Pois utilizando herança múltipla, precisa ter muito cuidado com os campos definidos. Por exemplo, tanto `Material` quanto `Geometria` possuem o campo `nome`, então qual deverá ser o `nome` de `SecTrans`? Use herança múltipla somente quando tiver certeza do que está fazendo. Se `SecTrans` somente depende dos valores das outras, não vejo nem porque utilizar herança neste caso. Apenas passá-los como parâmetro já seria suficiente.

Comment: A classe material é em relação ao material utilizado. Por exemplo, concreto, aço, madeira, etc. Cada um tem um E e ni diferente.  A classe geometria trata das áreas e momentos de inércia da seção transversal da barra de concreto, aço, madeira estudada e já a classe SecTrans calcula a rigidez da barra em questão, que depende do material e da geometria. Não sei se fui muito clara, sou péssima em explicações

Comment: Então leia sobre composição de classes.

Answer (score 0):

Como comentado por Anderson Carlos Woss, é preciso ter cuidado com a herança múltipla, no seu caso, eu vejo da seguinte forma:
Uma seção transversal **tem** um `Material` e uma `Geometria`, mas, não é por si mesma, nem um material nem uma forma/figura geométrica.

Da pra entender a diferença? Tem ambas as características mas não é uma "descendente" delas.

Um exemplo de classe que herdaria `Material` poderia ser `Concreto` por exemplo, como `Cubo` poderia herdar de `Geometria` e assim vai.. (isto é claro, implicando que as classes passariam a ser abstratas)

Em relação ao código, algo assim deveria servir:

```
# Remove a herança
class SecTrans(object):
  pass  # Colocar o resto aqui

material = Material('Queijo', 3, 5)
geometria = Geometria('Circulo')
transversal = SecTrans(material.E, geometria.A, 6, 7, 8)
```